# Tuple of string and list

Tags: python, list

Lets say the days of the week are in a ordered list:

```
    days_week=['mon','tues','wed','thurs','fri','sat']
```

The function I'm making recieves a list of randomly occuring elements in `days_week`:

```
    random_list=['mon','mon','mon','wed','sat','fri','fri','wed']
```

And then it should output a tuple of the highest occuring day and a list of the occurences of each day in the the right order as in `days_week` e.g. all mon's first, then all tue's:

```
    output:('mon',[3,0,2,0,2,1])
```

My first thought was to build a dictionary of keys that are the names of the week, and values that are the occurences of those days:

```
    days_dictionary={}
    for i in random_list:
          if i in days_dictionary:
               days_dictionary[i]+=1
          else:
               days_dictionary[i]=1
```

and that's where I'm stuck because I'm not sure how I would use the dictionary to form the output above.

edit: i cant import anything other than math

Comment: can you explain the output a little more...

Comment: its a tuple consisting of a string and a list where the string is the highest occuring day, and the list is the amount of occurences of each day in the order of mon's first then tue's and so on

Comment: Then isn't your example wrong?  It should be [3,0,2,0,2,1]

Comment: oh yes happydave your right my bad

Comment: Ok, I assumed they were ordered from highest to lowest. It's not very useful if the zeros aren't in there, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should be able to use these two expressions with your days_dictionary

```
>>> max(days_dictionary, key=days_dictionary.get)
'mon'
>>> [days_dictionary.get(k, 0) for k in days_week]
[3, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1]
```

Another way is to use a `collections.Counter`

```
>>> import random
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> days_week = ['mon', 'tues', 'wed', 'thurs', 'fri', 'sat']
>>> random_list = [random.choice(days_week) for x in range(10)]
>>> random_list
['wed', 'mon', 'mon', 'tues', 'tues', 'mon', 'wed', 'mon', 'wed', 'sat']
>>> c = Counter(random_list)
>>> c.most_common(1)[0][0]
'mon'
>>> [c.get(k, 0) for k in days_week]
[4, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1]
>>> c.most_common(1)[0][0], [c.get(k, 0) for k in days_week]
('mon', [4, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1])
```

Comment: unfortunatly the rules for this cerain excercise require me to use straight python without importing anything and also the output should have been: ('mon',[4,2,3,0,0,1]) because there are 4 mondays 2 tuesdays 3 wednesdays no thursdays or fridays and 1 saturday

Comment: Neat! `max(d, key=d.get)` is very elegant.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest having a look at [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> days_week=['mon','tues','wed','thurs','fri','sat']
>>> import random
>>> random_list = [random.choice(days_week) for _ in range(10)]
>>> print random_list
['mon', 'fri', 'sat', 'wed', 'sat', 'thurs', 'wed', 'sat', 'tues', 'tues']
>>> import itertools
>>> g = itertools.groupby(sorted(enumerate(random_list), key=lambda x: x[1]), lambda x: x[1])
>>> for day, occur in g:
    print day, list(occur)


fri [(1, 'fri')]
mon [(0, 'mon')]
sat [(2, 'sat'), (4, 'sat'), (7, 'sat')]
thurs [(5, 'thurs')]
tues [(8, 'tues'), (9, 'tues')]
wed [(3, 'wed'), (6, 'wed')]
```

Answer (score 1):

First: you can use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to build your dictionary:

```
from collections import Counter
random_list = ['mon','mon','mon','wed','sat','fri','fri','wed']
counts = Counter(random_list)
```

Then you can build the frequency list like so:

```
days_week = ['mon','tues','wed','thurs','fri','sat']
freqs = [counts[d] for d in days_week if d in counts]
```

And for the final output:

```
output = counts.most_common(1)[0][0], freqs ## ('mon', [3, 2, 2, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to get the most common day, like so:

```
import operator
most_common = max(days_dictionary.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

then make the list of the rest of the occurrences

```
occur = [days_dictionary[day] for day in days_week]
```

then make the tuple

```
(most_common, occur)
```

Comment: see my answer for a neater way to get the key of the maximum value of a dict